# Dynamic Sum of Fields MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

I've table materials which has relation with table cost prices which has multiple records quantities.

Now i have another table which is receipts when i make a receipt it shortens the sum of quantities by quantity of receipt.

is there anyway in `MySQL` to add **dynamic** field which calculates the sum quantities and keeps eye on change like when i sell (make receipt) it's dynamically shortens the sum of quantities ?
this is the schema in Laravel

//receipts

```
     Schema::create('receipts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('client_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('material_id');
        $table->double('payroll',8,2);
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->integer('type');
        $table->timestamps();

      });

      Schema::create('cost_prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('material_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('supplier_id');
        $table->integer('cost_price');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: well in such cases, you can create a trigger for SQL. However in Laravel, there is a concept of the Laravel Model Events that will trigger the particular event of that model, So either one of them will help you.

Comment: i think it's a good idea using model binding.thank you i'll try it

Comment: Read from here will help https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events